# Selenium Webdriver Python How to get text from the input tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the value of a textfield.  The textfield is in an Input tag in the html.  I want to print out it's value.
I am getting nothing printed out to the console.
I have identified the element with the following XPATH

```
By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" and contains(text(), "Type")]/following-sibling::*'
```

My code snippet is

```
 def get_type_field_value(self):
        type_field_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" and contains(text(), "Type")]/following-sibling::*'')
        print type_field_element.text
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="clear">
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" style="width: 8em;">Type</span>
    <input class="gwt-TextBox marginbelow" type="text" disabled="" style="display: inline;"/>
 </div>
```

I have also tried the following method:

```
def get_type_field_value2(self):
    return self.driver.execute_script("""
        return jQuery(arguments[0]).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
        }).text();
        """, self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" and contains(text(), "Type")]/following-sibling::*'))
```

I get a JavaScript error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: JavaScript error
```

How do i get the value of the Textfield?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no text in the html of the `<input>` tag.

Comment: So i cannot use.Text then.  How do i get the value then. Ah i could use .value.  Value is for input tags. I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since value is simply an html attribute, you can get the attribute value using -

```
print type_field_element.get_attribute('value')
```