# How to retrieve the text from an input element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am use python and selenium to go to a website that generates a random email. I am trying to store that email in a variable and return it.

```
def getemail(self):

    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://temp-mail.org/en/")
    time.sleep(2)
    ne = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mail']").text
    return ne
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is the kind of Selenium issue that comes up a lot, but isn't really a good SO question; it's likely that your locator is not correctly written. Please follow [this guide](https://openwritings.net/pg/python/python-selenium-debugging) on debugging issues where you can't find an element in Selenium.

Comment: Are you sure that driver.get("https://temp-mail.org/en/") is working? Try to print "driver" variable first. So, you can know that problem is here or in next lines :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver Python How to get text from the input tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630986/selenium-webdriver-python-how-to-get-text-from-the-input-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `<input>` and email is in its attribute `value=""`, not as text between opening and closing tag.

```
ne = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mail']").get_attribute("value")
```

---

**EDIT:** as suggested @JeffC in comment it could use `find_element_by_id`

```
ne = driver.find_element_by_id("mail").get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: If you are going to search for an element by nothing but an ID, please please please use `*_by_id()`. There's no reason not to. I know OP posted that but we should suggest best practices when we can improve their code, even if it's not what was specifically asked.

Comment: @JeffC you are right. Frankly, I didn't even look at xpath. I only checked if there is no `_elements_` with `"s"` at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

@furas answer was pretty close. However to extract the *random email address* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#mail"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='mail']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just get this by `get_attribute`.

Change the second last line of your code to this:

```
ne = driver.find_element_by_id("mail").get_attribute("value")
```